# Multilevel StdClass Object, print result

Tags: php, stdclass

First post here, but couldnt find any good results when searching..

Data is from a third party API via SOAP.

Im trying to print the value of an object, but only gets:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in xx.

Tried `$results->Info->First->One2;`

```
1object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["Info"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (27) {
["First"]=>
object(stdClass)#5 (7) {
  ["One1"]=>
  NULL
  ["One2"]=>
  NULL
  ["One3"]=>
  NULL
}
["Second"]=>
object(stdClass)#6 (7) {
  ["Two1"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Two2"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["Two3"]=>
  string(3) "1WL"
  }
 }
}
```

´

```
stdClass Object
(
[Info] => stdClass Object
    (
        [First] => stdClass Object
            (
                [One1] => value1
                [One2] => value2
                [One3] => value3
            )
    [Second] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Two1] => value4
                [Two2] => value5
                [Two3] => value6
                )
    )
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that all are stdClass objects here? What was in place `xx` in the error message? What's wrong in expressing that?

Comment: Yes only stdclass objects, no arrays..
xx was just the url and the line in code.

Br.

Comment: Did you try a `var_dump($results)`? For some reasons, API may not send the data at all.

Comment: Edited the question with the var_dump.
@TaReQMahMooD

Comment: Mention that its coming from `var_dump($results)`. Anyways, I don't see any problem, except that you have an extra `1` at the beginning. Pls wait for other's help.

Comment: Well thank you for answering.

Did get it to work now tho.. Still no idea why it didnt work in the beginning...

Thanks :)